# SQL- Grouping and counting # of days w/o overlapping days

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am trying to group a total count of days within a month that a patient had a catheter line inserted. The data is broken down into stints so is not contiguous throughout the month. I also do not to count overlapping days between the stints. See screenshot and query below.

[image]

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME

SET @start_date = '2/1/2022'
SET @end_date = '2/28/2022';

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Patient_ID     INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,startdate      DATE  NOT NULL
  ,enddate        DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Type_of_Line   VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,Insertion_Date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Removal_Date   DATE 
  ,_of_Cath_Days  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-01-16','2022-02-11','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,11);
INSERT INTO mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-11','2022-02-15','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-15','2022-02-24','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,10);
INSERT INTO mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-24','2022-03-23','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,5);


WITH stat
     AS (SELECT pt.ptkey,
                ptid,
                ptptinfusionstatus.startdate,
                ptptinfusionstatus.enddate
                
         FROM   pt
                LEFT JOIN ptptinfusionstatus
                       ON ptptinfusionstatus.ptkey = pt.ptkey
                LEFT JOIN ptinfusionstatus
                       ON ptinfusionstatus.ptinfusionstatuskey =
                          ptptinfusionstatus.ptinfusionstatuskey
                
         WHERE  ptptinfusionstatus.ptinfusionstatuskey IN ( 1, 5 )),

     access1
     AS (SELECT d.NAME,
                d.pharmacyeventandoutcometypedetailkey,
                T.pharmacyeventandoutcometypekey
         FROM   pharmacyeventandoutcometypedetail d WITH (nolock)
                LEFT JOIN pharmacyeventandoutcometype t WITH (nolock)
                       ON t.pharmacyeventandoutcometypekey =
                          d.pharmacyeventandoutcometypekey
                LEFT JOIN pharmacyeventandoutcomelist l WITH (nolock)
                       ON l.pharmacyeventandoutcomelistkey =
                          t.pharmacyeventandoutcomelistkey
         WHERE  l.pharmacyeventandoutcomelistkey = 2),
     
     access2
     AS (SELECT stat.ptkey,
                stat.ptid,
                stat.startdate,
                stat.enddate,
                Isnull(devicetype.NAME, '') [Access Device_Type],
                ppad.insertiondate          [Access Device_Insertion Date],
                ppad.removaldate            [Access Device_Removal Date]
         FROM   stat WITH (nolock)
                JOIN pharmacyptaccessdevice ppad WITH(nolock)
                  ON ppad.ptkey = stat.ptkey
                          LEFT JOIN access1 devicetype WITH (nolock)
                       ON devicetype.pharmacyeventandoutcometypedetailkey =
                          ppad.accessdevicetypekey
                          AND devicetype.pharmacyeventandoutcometypekey = 4)
       
       

--***MAIN QUERY***
SELECT access2.[ptid] AS 'Patient ID',
       access2.startdate,
       access2.enddate,
       access2.[access device_type] AS 'Type of Line',
       access2.[access device_insertion date] AS 'Insertion Date',
       access2.[access device_removal date] AS 'Removal Date',
       Datediff(d, CASE WHEN [access device_insertion date] >= @start_date AND
       [access device_insertion date] >=access2.startdate THEN
       access2.[access device_insertion date] WHEN access2.startdate >=
       access2.[access device_insertion date] AND
       access2.startdate >= @start_date THEN access2.startdate ELSE @start_date
       END,
       CASE WHEN @end_date <= Isnull(access2.enddate, @end_date) AND @end_date
       <= Isnull(access2.[access device_removal date], @end_date) THEN @end_date
       WHEN access2.enddate IS NOT NULL AND access2.enddate < @end_date AND
       access2.enddate <= Isnull(access2.[access device_removal date],
       access2.enddate) THEN access2.enddate ELSE
       access2.[access device_removal date] END) + 1 AS '# of Cath Days'
FROM   access2
WHERE  access2.startdate <= @end_date
       AND ( access2.enddate >= @start_date
              OR access2.enddate IS NULL )
       AND access2.[access device_insertion date] <= @end_date
       AND ( access2.[access device_removal date] >= @start_date
              OR access2.[access device_removal date] IS NULL )
       AND access2.ptid = '10247'
```

I tried grouping by patient and adding a sum of days at the patient group level in SQL Reporting Services, but could not get around the overlapping days so the counts are all wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided, below is an example code that will group based on patientId and if start date equals end date then it will subtract 1 from number of days.

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME

SET @start_date = '2/1/2022'
SET @end_date = '2/28/2022';

declare @mytable table(
   Patient_ID     INTEGER  NOT NULL -- PRIMARY KEY 
  ,startdate      DATE  NOT NULL
  ,enddate        DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Type_of_Line   VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,Insertion_Date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Removal_Date   DATE 
  ,_of_Cath_Days  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-01-16','2022-02-11','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,11);
INSERT INTO @mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-11','2022-02-15','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,5);
INSERT INTO @mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-15','2022-02-24','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,10);
INSERT INTO @mytable(Patient_ID,startdate,enddate,Type_of_Line,Insertion_Date,Removal_Date,_of_Cath_Days) VALUES (10247,'2022-02-24','2022-03-23','Port','2021-08-03 00:00:00.000',NULL,5);

    select
    Patient_ID
    , startdate
    , enddate
    , Type_of_Line
    , Insertion_Date
    , Removal_Date
    , LAG([enddate]) OVER (ORDER BY [startdate]) as compareenddate
    from @mytable



select Patient_ID
    , min(startdate) as startdate
    , max(enddate) as enddate
    , max(Type_of_Line) as Type_of_Line
    , min(Insertion_Date) as Insertion_Date
    , max(Removal_Date) as Removal_Date
    , sum(iif(startdate = isnull(compareenddate, '1900-01-01'), _of_Cath_Days - 1, _of_Cath_Days) )
from 
(
    select
    Patient_ID
    , startdate
    , enddate
    , Type_of_Line
    , Insertion_Date
    , Removal_Date
    , _of_Cath_Days
    , LAG([enddate]) OVER (ORDER BY [startdate]) as compareenddate
    from @mytable
) x
group by Patient_ID
```

Query result

[image: Result of query]